# Characterization of pseudo monomorphisms and pseudo epimorphisms in Cat

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a known characterization (and possibly a reference) for pseudomono and pseudoepi in Cat?

For lax-epi, and small categories, the answer is in the paper [*On functors which are lax epimorphisms*](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n20/8-20abs.html) (Adámek, El Bashir, Sobral, Velebil 2001).

Comment: It's easy to prove that the pseudomonics (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudomonic+functor) are just the functors that are (1) faithful and (2) full onto isomorphisms.  The pseudoepis would probably be much harder to characterize.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was expecting.

Comment: @MikeShulman, Does it make sense to think that a functor which is full and (essentially) surjective on objects is a pseudoepi?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you would show the relevant functor to be full on isos.  But it might be true.

Comment: Just as localizations give examples of non-surjective epimorphisms of rings, so too the natural functor $B\mathbb N \to B \mathbb Z$ is an example of a pseudoepic which is not full (or even full on isos).

Comment: That’s the other implication!